# How to share data among all the views/controllers/users

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC application, I am using entity framework, There is a master table whose data is accessed among different views & controllers by all users.

I want to keep the data of this master table into some shared variable/session or anything so that it can be accessed by all users. As this is a master table it is data is common for all.

I tried using TempData, ViewBag but there data does not persist if we redirect to different views & controllers. I tried sessions as well, but I do not want to have each user keeping a copy in memory.

What is the best way to store such data in MVC application

Atul Sureka

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Runtime Cache object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in ASP.Net MVC to keep all the common data. Cached data can be accessed fast and we have other benefits like expiring cache etc.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for Application State http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf9xhdz4%28VS.71%29.aspx it is like session state but shared across all connected users (global session).

Answer (score 0):

You can put them in the Application:

```
Application["GlobalVar"] = 1234;
```

They are only global within the current IIS / Virtual applicition. This means, on a webfarm they are local to the server, and within the virtual directory that is the root of the application.